# Calling Tableau API with an embedded user

Tags: tableau-api

I'm currently utilizing tableau API to embed graphs published onto our server. Our server doesn't allow guest users because of company polices, but the server is internal, and one of the graphs we have is suposed to be shares with anyone willing to see it. The problem is that not everyone have access to Tableau Server, because we are charger by each user, monthly.

So the question is, is it possible to embed a specific user's authentication into a webpage?
Another question is, if it is possible, does the user have a limit of multiple connections at the same time?

Comment: This sounds like you are asking how to violate the software license agreement. Might be better to find a solution that doesn't violate your contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to export your visualizations as static images which you then make available via a traditional web page. You can automate the image capture on a schedule easily, say by appending .png to the Tableau Server viz url and using a script to request the image and save to disk periodically. That way the image can stay up to date with data changes.

This produces static images without interactivity, but it respects the license agreement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This way is just what I have been looking for, but just a question. Do I still need to embed the resource user to the image extraction automation? If so, do you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes the user that connects to tableau server needs to be a licensed user. The easiest way to do this use the tabcmd command line utility, or the REST API